# Anatomically Correct Godzilla

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, evolution

There have been countless online articles that go into painstaking detail about the implausibility of Godzilla existing in real life. But, let's just assume that a creature like Godzilla naturally evolved (rather than being a amphibious dinosaur mutated by an H-bomb or a prehistoric marine reptile that was heavily mutated due to feeding off radioactive materials dumped in the ocean) in order to:

- Attain a massive size of several hundred feet (and the ability to support its massive bulk without being crushed underneath it)
- Develop an upright stance similar to that of a Kangaroo or tail-dragging Tyrannosaurus Rex
- Have adaptations that allow for an amphibious lifestyle (staying underwater for long periods of time without going up to breathe)
- Be impervious to conventional weaponry and have the ability to quickly recover from fatal injuries

And last, but not least...

- Fire a powerful beam of atomic energy from its mouth, which has the destructive force of an atomic bomb

What would the evolution of a such creature look like?

Comment: Surely the "reality-check" tag is pointless for a creature as mind numbingly obviously impossible.  "Fire a powerful beam of atomic energy from its mouth" alone should tell you this.

Comment: Umm, "have the ability to quickly recover from fatal injuries", if the injury can be recovered from at all (let alone quickly), it isn't fatal, since a fatal injury kills whatever is injured by definition.

Comment: "an atomic bomb" is exceptionally imprecise as a measure of destructive power. It could mean everything from a small "suitcase" nuclear weapon right up to the Tsar Bomba, let alone how atomic bombs can be optimized for destructive power or for radiation (for the latter, think for example "neutron bomb").

Answer (score 8):

Succinctly...

### It Wouldn't

Caveat - this assumes that the distinct-for-legal-reasons pseudo-Godzilla evolved using life processes similar to those found on earth.  While other building blocks have been speculated upon, no one has a solid idea of what anything beyond single-celled creatures based on (for example) silicon would look like, so speculation on mega-fauna is just shots in the dark.

Taking your points one at a time:

- **Height of "several hundred feet"** - notwithstanding collapsing under its own weight (which it would certainly do outside of water - no bone is strong enough to support even its own weight, let alone supporting muscle), land animals [cannot get that tall](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/why-king-kong-should-have-been-blue-whale-180962603/).  The structure would be untenable, blood pressure would have to be astonishingly high... you just can't have anything much taller than the tallest dinosaurs of antiquity.  So you're limited to circa 18m.

  In addition to this, the only reason anything would evolve to that size would be if there were sufficient prey around to justify the enormous investment.  Whales can manage it by grazing - dinosaurs because there were other dinosaurs.  The sheer volume of food required by a multi-hundred-foot monster might make it completely untenable in and of itself; it would have to be constantly eating just to stay alive.
- **Developing an Upright Stance** - Allowing for the first impossible bullet point, the reason for this is the same as other bipedal evolutions - speed and reach.  All other things being equal, two legs are more maneuverable and faster than four.
- **Adaptations to allow for an amphibious lifestyle** - amphibians exist.  Whole groups of creatures that can stay underwater indefinitely.  No conflict here, aside from gas exchange problems (the reason the largest creatures are mammals is because lungs are way more efficient (half again as efficient) as gills.  So your giant creature will have trouble getting sufficient oxygen underwater, but if it's mostly sessile, that's potentially addressable.
- **Be impervious to conventional weaponry and have the ability to quickly recover from fatal injuries** - Armour, scaled up, could resist many ballistic weapons - [just look at armadillos](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/bulletproof-armadillo-puts-texas-man-in-hospital-after-shot-bounces-off-hard-shell-10432102.html).  A minor point here, but if it's a *fatal* injury, recovery is, by definition, impossible.  Rapid recovery from grievous injuries is potentially possible (for example, [the axolotl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axolotl#Regeneration)), but the energetic cost of healing is proportional to the size of the organism, so it's hard to imagine that your monster could also carry around enough fat (in addition to its impossible mass) to power the process.

Final point:

- **Atomic breath** - nope.  There is no chemical process that approaches the destructive power of an atomic weapon, and and no potential biological material that would be capable of shaping and resisting the forces involved, even if there were.  Assuming that some magical energy source were employed, the only way it could be shaped would be if a good part of the projecting orifice (the mouth, in this case) were ablated in the process.

All of this assumes, as I said, that we're using carbon-based, earth-like life.  It's possible that something resembling life but using processes entirely different from what we're familiar with could address some of these issues.  Some of the height issues could be addressed by the creature living on a very low-gravity planet.  But assuming you want this thing to be able to tap-dance through Tokyo, it's straight-up impossible.  There is no conceivable evolutionary path.

Answer (score 0):

**Well, it is possible to make a Godzilla-like creature, but it wouldn't be so big.**

- **Attain a massive size of several hundred feet**

  Impossible. It would collapse. Land animals can't get that big, they wouldn't support their own weight. But, it is possible to make them big as a Tyrannosaurus.
- **Develop an upright stance similar to that of a Kangaroo or tail-dragging Tyrannosaurus Rex**

  Well, if you use the Tyrannosaurus Rex as a base for the "Godzilla", you can get pretty far. It could have a Tyrannosaurus-like tail.
- **Have adaptations that allow for an amphibious lifestyle**

  The [spinosaurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinosaurus) is known as the only dinosaur that swims. if you add this to your Godzilla, he will be able to swim. Maybe not as an amphibian, but almost?
- **Be impervious to conventional weaponry and have the ability to quickly recover from fatal injuries**

  He could have an armadillo-like armor or super resistant scales, but it is impossible to recover quickly from wounds.
- **Fire a powerful beam of atomic energy from its mouth, which has the destructive force of an atomic bomb**

  Sorry, but this part is impossible.